# Deploy Laravel Project to AWS 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, iis

**The base route working correctly and open the website, but the issue in other routes get 404 not found**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I've solved the issue you need to import .htaccess file to the urlwriter in IIS settings on your site:**

1. install url writer
2. go to your site
3. duble click on url writer
4. click Import Roles
5. select the .htaccess
6. click import button
7. If you have issues, you need to remove *RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]* line from .htaccess
8. then return to import again
9. click on apply and open your site again

**resource on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afow0RsMvxI) menute 16:00**

Comment: Hi, you have the second line identical to first